# How to send two variable by Ajax in same time ( by javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a textarea to post and a PHP variables. I made script like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.post').keyup(function(e){
        var post = $.trim($('.post').val());
        if (post != "" && e.keyCode === 13 && e.shiftKey === false) {
            $.post('send.php', { post: post }, function(data) {
                $('.post').val('');
            });
        }
    });

    var to = "<?php echo $name;?>";
     $.post('send.php', { to: to }, function(data){ });     
});
```

After sending, I made a query to store in database, but as I sent two variable(post and to) in different time, so, in database every time two rows are generated where first row get only "to" variable and 2nd row get "post" variable.

how to change the above javascript codes so that i can get one row each time(with "post" && "to" variable)

Comment: `{post:post, to:to}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add another variable to *data*

```
var to="<?php echo $name;?>";
$.post('send.php',{post:post, to:to},function(data){
    $('.post').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the second argument of the `post` function in jQuery is an object meaning you can add as many things to it as possible

```
$.post(url,
    {
        var1:val1,
        var2:val2,
        varN:valN
    },
    function(data) {
        $('.post').val('');
});
```